# Serializing .NET object to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I tried the following code to serialize a .NET object to JSON, but i keep getting blank text. What am I doing wrong?

```
[DataContract]
        public class JsonObject2
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "field1")]
            string field1 { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "field2")]
            string field2 { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "field3")]
            string[] test = { "heshan", "perera" };
        }
```

The object, I attempt to serialize and display the resulting JSON string in a message box, but all i get is blank.

```
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();

            DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer((typeof(JsonObject2)));
            JsonObject2 obj2 = new JsonObject2();
            dcjs2.WriteObject(s, obj2);

            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s);
            String x = r.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(x);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
s.Position = 0;
```

just before you create the `StreamReader.`